# How can I configure webpack for use with Symfony 4 projects

Tags: symfony4, babeljs

I just installed Babel via the command `npm install --save @ babel / preset-env`, Once installed, I created a ".babelrc" file at the root and put the following config: `{"presets": ["@ babel / preset-env"]}`.

Despite that I get the error below:

> WARNING The "callback" argument of configureBabel() will not be used because your app already provides an external Babel configuration (a ".babelrc" file, ".babelrc.js" file or "babel" key in "package.json"). Use null as a first argument to remove that warning. DEPRECATION configureBabel: "include_node_modules" is deprecated. Please use "includeNodeModules" instead. Error: "includeNodeModules" and "exclude" options can't be used together when calling configureBabel().

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had the same error and i solved with this configurations (sorry my english is not good): 
In file : **webpack.config.js**:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
// Directorio donde se almacenarán los assets ya compilados.
.setOutputPath('public/build/')

.setPublicPath('/build')

// Nuestro archivo app.js, que será compilado y almacenado en /web/build/app.js
.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
// .addEntry('buscarRepuesto', './assets/js/Components/buscar repuesto/buscarRepuesto.js')

// Habilitar el mapeo de recursos en Desarrollo.
.enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

// Borra el contenido del directorio /web/build antes de volver a compilar una nueva versión.
.cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()

// Muestra una notificación cuando se ha finalizado la compilación.
.enableBuildNotifications()

// Activa React
.enableReactPreset()
;

// Exporta la configuración final
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

And in my file **.babelrc**:

```
{
"presets": [
   "@babel/preset-env",
   "@babel/preset-react"
],
"plugins": [
    [ 
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
 ]
 }
```

And my **packages.json** was:

```
{
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
  "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.29.1",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
  "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
  "react": "^16.13.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
  "webpack-notifier": "^1.8.0"
},
"dependencies": {
  "node-sass": "^4.14.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"
}
}
```